# vim/gvim close nerdtree after start from shell

Tags: shell, vim, git-merge

I would like to close NerdTree on vim startup using shell arguments. Something like this:

```
vim +NERDTreeClose file.txt
```

or

```
vim -c "NERDTreeClose" file.txt
```

should do the trick, but it doesn't. Automatic start of NERDTree is defined inside .vimrc (by `autocmd vimenter * NERDTree`) and it should stay there.

The point of all this is to configure vim as a mergetool so I don't need NERDTree opening on startup.

Comment: If we forget for a minute that an always on file explorer is beyond useless, did you consider the opposite strategy : open NERDTree *only* if vim is not used as a mergetool?

Comment: That's also a good solution but I have no idea how to determine (in .vimrc) if vim is running as mergetool or not.

Comment: `v:progname` tells you the name under which Vim was invoked. Assuming you use `vimdiff`, executing `NERDTree` in the "false" branch of a simple conditional should be enough.

Comment: Unfortunatelly for merging I use regular `gvim` (because gvimdiff throws a lot of errors) with `Gdiff` command but thanks for the hint

Comment: Fugitive's `:Gdiff`? If so you are *not* using Vim as a "mergetool".

Comment: Yes, you got it right I'm using Fugitive's diff but Vim as an editor.

Comment: "configure vim as a mergetool" means that you are "using Vim as your mergetool" but that's not what you seem to be doing at all. Something like `nnoremap ,d :NERDTreeClose<bar>Gdiff<CR>` may very well be all you need. Please describe your workflow more precisely.

Comment: In my .gitconfig I have line [mergetool "gvim"] `cmd = gvim -f -c \"Gdiff\" \"$MERGED\"` and this is my default merge tool, so basically when I hit ENETER to resolve merge GVim pops up. All I need is to hide NERDTree when it starts.